# can't group by anagram correctly

Tags: python, string, algorithm, hashtable

I wrote a python function to group a list of words by anagram:

```
def groupByAnagram(list):
    dic = {}
    for x in list:
        sort = ''.join(sorted(x))

        if sort in dic == True:
            dic[sort].append(x)
        else:
            dic[sort] = [x]

    for y in dic:
        for z in dic[y]:
            print z

groupByAnagram(['cat','tac','dog','god','aaa'])
```

but this only returns:

aaa

god

tac

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: @MartinThoma I expected  all 5 words:
aaa
dog
god
cat
tac

in that order

Comment: Not related to your issue, but `if sort in dic == True:` should be written simply `if sort in dic:`.

Comment: That exactly what's causing the problem.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath thanks that made it work... can you explain why?

Comment: Python guarantees no ordering for the keys in a dictionary. Your expected output could be inconsistent. That being said, your if condition needs a paranthetical grouping. The operator '==' likely has precedence over 'in'.

Comment: Sidenote: you can use a `defaultdict` to simplify your code.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath indeed, that's good to know! i wouldn't have suspected the operator's priorities

Comment: @SpencerBrett: no, if it were a precedence rule, you would get `TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable` (as the comparison results in a bool)

Answer (score 9):

```
if sort in dic == True:
```

Thanks to [operator chaining](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), this line is equivalent to

```
if (sort in dic) and (dic == True):
```

But dic is a dictionary, so it will never compare equal to True. Just drop the == True comparison entirely.

```
if sort in dic:
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the "== True" in your if clause. You can just check with sort in dic.

change the if-clause to:

```
if sort in dic:
```

and everything works as expected.

You can also remove the if-clause by using the default dict of the collections package. This way you do not have to check if you have to create a new list for your dict, each time.

```
import collections
def groupByAnagram2(word_list):
    dic = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for x in word_list:
       sort = ''.join(sorted(x))
       dic[sort].append(x)

    for words in dic.values():
        for word in words:
            print word
```